# Frames appearing out of order on GLSurfaceView

Tags: android, animation, opengl-es, glsurfaceview, doublebuffered

I'm writing an Android app using OpenGL ES and encountered this problem in the Nexus 5 emulator that comes with Android Studio. I have reduced my code to this small app, which simply draws a box going back and forth:

```
package net.jesbus.stuttertest;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.opengl.GLSurfaceView;
import android.os.Bundle;

import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.ByteOrder;
import java.nio.FloatBuffer;
import java.nio.ShortBuffer;

import javax.microedition.khronos.egl.EGLConfig;
import javax.microedition.khronos.opengles.GL10;

public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Create GLSurfaceView
        GLSurfaceView glsv = new GLSurfaceView(this);
        glsv.setEGLConfigChooser(8, 8, 8, 8, 16, 0);

        // Create GLSurfaceView.Renderer
        glsv.setRenderer(new GLSurfaceView.Renderer()
        {
            float step = 0;
            boolean direction = false;
            ShortBuffer iBuff;
            FloatBuffer vBuff;
            @Override
            public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig config)
            {
                // Generate vertices index buffer
                short[] pIndex = {0, 1, 2, 3};
                ByteBuffer pbBuff = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(pIndex.length * 2);
                pbBuff.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
                iBuff = pbBuff.asShortBuffer();
                iBuff.put(pIndex);
                iBuff.position(0);

                // Generate vertices buffer
                float[] vs = new float[]
                        {
                                -1, +1, 0,
                                +1, +1, 0,
                                -1, -1, 0,
                                +1, -1, 0,
                        };
                ByteBuffer bBuff = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(vs.length * 4);
                bBuff.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
                vBuff = bBuff.asFloatBuffer();
                vBuff.put(vs);
                vBuff.position(0);
            }

            @Override
            public void onDrawFrame(final GL10 gl)
            {
                // Animation calculation
                step += direction ? 0.02f : -0.02f;
                if (step > 1) direction = false;
                else if (step < 0) direction = true;

                // Set background color
                gl.glClearColor(0.7f, 0.7f, 1, 1);

                // Clear screen
                gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL10.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

                // Set matrix to correct location
                gl.glLoadIdentity();
                gl.glTranslatef(-1 + step * 2, 0, 0);
                gl.glScalef(0.25f, 0.4f, 1);

                // Draw box
                gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
                gl.glFrontFace(GL10.GL_CW);
                gl.glVertexPointer(3, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, vBuff);
                gl.glDrawElements(GL10.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 4, GL10.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, iBuff);
                gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
            }

            @Override
            public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int width, int height)
            {
            }
        });
        setContentView(glsv);
    }
}
```

I looked at it frame by frame, and it seems that instead of showing the next frame, it shows the previous frame, and then skips the frame it was supposed to show and continues:

[image: Wrong order of frames]

The circles represent frames produced in onDrawFrame, and the arrows represent the flow of time.

[Video showing the problem](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pv-28zyT3zM)

Comment: Have you seen this on an actual device? The BufferQueue mechanism is pretty straightforward, but the connection between GLES and the emulator GPU acceleration is nontrivial.

Answer (score 0):

I don't exactly know how threading is used OpenGL, but try this:

```
    // Animation calculation
    synchronized (this) {
        step += direction ? 0.02f : -0.02f;
        if (step > 1) direction = false;
        else if (step < 0) direction = true;
    }
```

or make the whole `onDrawFrame()` method synchronized if the compiler consents and OpenGL doesn't lock up...

Comment: Unfortunately this does not solve the problem. I put a Log.i(...) at the top and bottom of the onDrawFrame method, and there is never an overlap. Even if there was, it would not cause the box to jump backwards in the middle of the animation (around step=0.5).

Comment: GLSurfaceView uses a dedicated renderer thread. Since all of the calculations are being done within `onDrawFrame()` there's no chance of a thread safety issue.